# DatePicker in StackExchange API document page should have year next & previous button also

Tags: feature-request

While picking for dates as shown in this snapshot[image], there should be one more next and previous button for year. It will be easy to navigate 1 year backward and forward on one click. Better option would be what is implemented in Time window in taskbar of Windows 7.